# Apk size increased drawable-xxxhdpi-v4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I am unable to figure this out. My apk size has increased by at least another MB since the last release. Yes, I **have** added some new code and couple of vector assets thats it. But there is this `drawable-xxxhdpi-v4` which got added to my apk and my png images are repeated there. 
Take a look.

[image: Summary]

[image: As you can see, old apk has 0 bytes for this folder and the new apk has my png assets copied there.]

**Has anybody faced this?**
I just cant seem to figure out why is this hapenning. Its not even like these are new images. The old ones which were 0 bytes in this folder are now occupying space.

Gradle version 2.14.1
Plugin version 2.2.3

App build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId project.APPLICATION_ID
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)

    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    versionName project.VERSION_NAME

    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true


    resConfigs "en", "fr"

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}

// This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "db"

}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

buildTypes {
    def BOOLEAN = "boolean"
    def TRUE = "true"
    def FALSE = "false"
    def LOGGING = "LOGGING"
    def STRICT_MODE = "STRICT_MODE"
    def DEBUG_MODE = "DEBUG_MODE"

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt', 'proguard-here-sdk.txt'
        // Resource shrinking confis
        shrinkResources true // remove unused resources
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        debuggable false
        buildConfigField BOOLEAN, LOGGING, FALSE
        buildConfigField BOOLEAN, STRICT_MODE, FALSE
        buildConfigField BOOLEAN, DEBUG_MODE, FALSE
        zipAlignEnabled true

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
                variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
                    delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeAssets.outputDir, includes: ['ic_launcher_debug*']))
                }
            }
        }
    }
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below config worked for me

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes. When you compile with Coccoon.io an android version of your app, it happens the same. The size of the app is increased at double. This is not only due to folders like this, but for the libraries Coccoon puts on the app for cordova.

I don´t know if that will help you, but al least is a clue.